# How can I train a PyTorch model to accurately detect the range of ellipses in an image and label them appropriately?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision

How can I identify the ellipse in the image and label the idea of the range？

I want to identify whether another object is inside the ellipse, and I trained a model to recognize objects more accurately, but the problem is that I have no idea how to detect the range of ellipses. Which model should I use to implement this function?

For example, how to identify the scoring area of the round target ring taken by the camera. At the moment my thinking is to use Segment Anything Model to segment the target paper area. Then use some models to identify elliptic regions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.